# What words and intentions are to be stressed at the end of Neilah?

Tags: hebrew, yom-kippur, kavana-concentration

I have heard different ways of stressing the words that we repeat seven times at the end of the Neilah service on Yom Kippur: יי הוּא הָאֱלֹהִים.

Are there any recorded thoughts on what is recommended to stress, either in terms of literal language use or in terms of intention and meaning?

For example, in English, there would be three subtly different meanings depending of which word you stress. This would not have to directly correspond to ones intention, but it often would.

Comment: Do you mean ways of stressing like pronunciation?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I have heard people pronouncing stressing different words of the three. Intention may or may not follow from word stress. In English, at least, there are three subtly different meanings depending on what you stress.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. I would like to elaborate three ways of reading this verse of which we also say on Yom Kippur. (Sephardim, Aseres Yimay Teshuvah and Hoshana Raba as well)

**Kings 1;18;39**

וַיַּרְא֙ כׇּל־הָעָ֔ם וַֽיִּפְּל֖וּ עַל־פְּנֵיהֶ֑ם וַיֹּ֣אמְר֔וּ **יְהֹוָה֙ ה֣וּא הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים יְהֹוָ֖ה ה֥וּא הָאֱלֹהִֽים**׃

And when all the people saw it, they fell on their faces; and they said: 'The Lord, He is God; the Lord, He is God

As a background, The Jews were committing Idol Worship and were convinced that "Baal" was a power worthy of Godlike worship. Eliyahu Hatishbi confronts them with a proposal that they will test who is the accurate God, and give an offering, if their offering is received then, they are correct. If Eliyahu's offering to Hashem the God of Heaven and Earth is received then he is right. Their offering was not received and Eliyahu's was received

**Passuk 38:**

"Then the fire of the Lord fell, and consumed the burnt-offering, and the wood, and the stones, and the dust, and licked up the water that was in the trench"

After seeing this they pronounce, **those words - ה הוא אלהים.**

There are three ways of how the Jews at that moment actually said those words, recorded in the Passuk.

1. The **שם המיוחד** is אלהים. The Strong Word is the first. הוא אלהים is the answer. ( **ה** הוא אלהים)
2. That God is God. There is no strong words. The change in God's name is just to clarify the statement.
3. That אלהים is the strong word. Saying that God (שם המיוחד) is אלהים.

It really depends on how they were serving the "Baal". If they were deeply connected to it, then the moment that they switched from "Baal" To God, would be option 1. If on the other hand their connection was a more of a worldly God connection, then it would be option 3. If this statement wasn't connected to anything in particular and it was just a declaration then it would be option 2.

Understandably Option #2 is the simple modern translation. Option 1 and 3 are dealing with the Deepness between these two names of God. It's not the place to discuss it, throughout the Torah there are commentaries who elaborate on that. (Ramban, Ibn Ezra, Rabbeinu Sadyah and countless others, Parshas Bereshis would be good start)

**Rashi (as well as the Radak, Metsudas David):**

He takes option 2.

י״י הוא האלהים – ולא הבעל האלהים.

God is God, and not the "Baal" the God.

**Malbim adds:** שרק ה׳ הוא האלהים but similar to Rashi.